# Rails 3. Keep the number of nested fields in form when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where I register a Student and 3 Emergency Contacts. (emergency_contact belongs to student).

So, StudentsController...

```
def new
  @student = Student.new
   3.times {@student.emergency_contacts.build}
...
```

So let's say, the user filled out student information and only ONE emergency contact. The validation fails for any reason (maybe student name wasn't entered), **when the form is redisplayed, the fields to enter a second or third additional emergency contacts are gone**.

Of course, if I do this `3.times {@member.caregivers.build}` in the create action too, I will get more and more additional fields each time the validation fails.

***So how can I always keep a specified number of nested models in a form, even after the validation fails?***

Answer (score 1):

In your create action, you can do:

```
if @student.save
  ...
else
 (3 - @student.emergency_contacts.size).times { @student.emergency_contacts.build }
end
```

hope it helps.